# Creating static function in Python using variables outside

Tags: python, scope

I need to create a set of similar static functions in python. This involves variables outside the function that I want to use as hard-coded values when a function is created. However, functions created this way remain linked to variables and change dynamically:

```
def repeat_n():
    res = []
    for _ in range(n):
        res.append(1)
    return res

n = 3
repeat_three = repeat_n
repeat_three()
n =+ 1
# repeats four times
repeat_three()
```

Comment: `repeat_three = repeat_n` doesn't create a *new function*. It's *the same function*

Comment: Even if it *did* copy the function, it wouldn't replace `n` with the value of `n` at the time of the copy. `n` is a free variable, whose value is looked up when you *call* the function.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment *never* creates a copy in Python, so `repeat_three = repeat_n` **doesn't create a new function, it merely assigns the same function object to another variable**.

It looks like you just want a function factory:

```
def repeat_factory(n):
    def repeat():
        res = []
        for _ in range(n):
            res.append(1)
        return res
    return repeat

repeat_3 = repeat_factory(3)
repeat_4 = repeat_factory(4)
```

Comment: thank you! this works indeed
`n = 3
def repeat_factory(n):
    def repeat():
        res = []
        for _ in range(n):
            res.append(1)
        return res
    return repeat

repeat_3 = repeat_factory(n)
n+=1
repeat_3()`